# What is the point of all the extra attributes returned in token response for PKCE

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

This is a sample response from Azure B2C [token endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#request-a-token)

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrN...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1549647431,
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "expires_on": 1549651031,
    "resource": "f2a76e08-93f2-4350-833c-965c02483b11",
    "profile_info": "eyJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAiLCJ0aWQiOiJjNjRhNGY3ZC0zMDkxLTRjNzMtYTcyMi1hM2YwNjk0Z..."
}
```

**What is the point of `not_before`, `expires_in`, and `expires_on`?** The token is already time limited.

Bonus points for figuring out `resource` and `profile_info` which are probably some MSFT specific crud that they [didn't even care to explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expires_in is OAuth specific and is recommended in the RFC
[RFC 6749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.3)

expires_on seems to be the same as a unix-timestamp

Resource is probably the ClientId? and Profile-Info an IdToken? But I am just guessing these two.

Comment: The RFC doesn't really explain why would it be useful to read that field though

Comment: It's normally used by clients, when they need to implement logic regarding these fields. Normally a clients should not have to understand the token. It should only use it, so some information is contained in the response.

Comment: Yes, I guess that makes sense for access tokens (as I understand id tokens can be parsed)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are described [here](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc.md).

**Profile_info**: A Base64-encoded JSON string that may contain useful information about the user for display in your native application. Its exact contents will depend on the application claims that you configured in your policy.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't answer my question. What is the use of this information if I already have `nbf` and `exp` claims in the token. Why should I use this profile information instead of id token?